# AspNet Core (RC1): AddClaims to a Role with RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am moving and translating a legacy membership system to Identity Core RC1. I am extracting a number of claims (up to 50 or more) for each role from the old system and I need to create the corresponding role and related claims in the new one.
The problem is that when I loop through the claims to add them to a role like this:

```
await RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, claim)
```

The system persists a few claims (sometimes 2 sometimes 7 or more) to the db then returns an error:

*New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.*

Or sometimes this kind of error:

*An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

Which has 4 levels of InnerException with the last one saying:

*BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.*

Is there something wrong in using AddClaimAsync? I have been going crazy on this and cannot find the way out. Any suggestions?

Here is the code:
- Custom RoleManager:

```
public class EMSRoleManager : RoleManager<EMSRole>
    {
        public EMSRoleManager(IRoleStore<EMSRole> store, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<EMSRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<RoleManager<EMSRole>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger, contextAccessor)
        {
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<EMSUser, EMSRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<EMSRoleManager>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>();
```

In the service class I am using I am inject as follows:

```
private UserManager<EMSUser> _userManager;
private LegacyIdentityContext _legacyDb;
private EMSRoleManager _roleManager;

public LoginService(UserManager<EMSUser> userManager, LegacyIdentityContext legacyIdentity, EMSRoleManager roleManager )
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _legacyDb = legacyIdentity;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
}
```

And then, given a list of claims, I am using this to add them to the role:

```
for (int i = 0; i < claims.Count; i++)
{
    await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(newRole, claims[i]);
}
```

Here is where it break.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: you might get more attention with RC2 in the title

Comment: Thank you, that is a good suggestion, the only issue I see is that my code is based on RC1, so I should probably update to RC2, which entails another set of issues, and then see if this is still a problem... I guess I will.